# How to display point nomenclature side by side (separated with a comma) which share exactly the same data points to prevent overlapping

Tags: excel, vba, plot, charts

I am getting point labels overlapping on my chart and was wondering how I would modify the attached code to prevent this from happening? Preferably I would like them to be separated by a comma.

Below is the code I have, which plots my data accurately on an effort vs benefit chart. Essentially the two scores determine whether the point ends up in the green, orange or red part of the chart depending on high or low benefit/effort. Could someone suggest an option for this? I am assuming it isn't much more than a line or so of code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("AllData")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

   Call AttachLabelsToPoints
End If
End Sub

Sub AttachLabelsToPoints()

 'Dimension variables.
   Dim Counter As Integer, ChartName As String, xVals As String

 ' Disable screen updating while the subroutine is run.
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  On Error GoTo Skip:
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
     For Counter = 1 To Range("Labels").Rows.Count
     ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = _
        True
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = _
     Range("Labels").Cells(Counter, 1).Value
 Next Counter
 Skip:
 End Sub
```

As you can see from the photo the number 3 and 5 are overlapping at the top in the green section. This would be preferable to have the data label represented as "3,5" as opposed to on top of one another? Any thoughts?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arGHY.png)

Comment: It's too late tonight to write a whole answer, but here's the gist. You need to check for points with the same coordinates, and (a) only plot the point once, (b) generate a combined label). Earlier tonight, in [Scatter Plot X,Y Coordinate Number of Occurrences](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1109538-scatter-plot-x-y-coordinate-number-occurrences.html#post5341189) I showed with worksheet formulas how to count the number of points with matching coordinates. It should be easy enough to work this into your VBA labeling routine.

Comment: Hi @JonPeltier thanks for getting in touch and the links! I will have an attempt at this, but not expecting much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then again, it's Stack Overflow, so here's my VBA solution.

The data is simpler, and the labels will consist of the point number from the original series (so assuming Project number just counts from 1 to N).

[image: non-overlapping labels]

And the VBA. It captures the X and Y values of the original data series, then loops through and generates arrays of X, Y, and labels for a new series. If it finds any existing points that match a previous point's X and Y, it doesn't add values to the new X and Y arrays; instead it appends the point number to the matched point's label.

It adds a new series to the chart using the new X and Y arrays, hides the markers, and adds labels.

```
Sub NonOverlappingLabels()
  If ActiveChart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Select a chart, and try again.", vbExclamation, "No Chart Selected"
  Else
    With ActiveChart
      With .SeriesCollection(1)
        Dim Xvals As Variant ' X values in series 1
        Xvals = .XValues
        Dim Yvals As Variant ' Y values in series 2
        Yvals = .Values
      End With

      Dim NewX As Variant ' X values for new series to hold labels
      ReDim NewX(1 To 1)
      Dim NewY As Variant ' Y values for new series to hold labels
      ReDim NewY(1 To 1)
      Dim Labels As Variant ' labels for new series
      ReDim Labels(1 To 1)

      Dim nPoints As Long ' number of points in NewX and NewY
      nPoints = 1
      NewX(1) = Xvals(1)
      NewY(1) = Yvals(1)
      Labels(1) = "1"

      Dim iLooper As Long
      For iLooper = 2 To UBound(Yvals) ' check subsequent points from series 1 for a match
        Dim FoundMatch As Boolean
        FoundMatch = False
        Dim iTest As Long
        For iTest = 1 To nPoints ' compare with values for new series
          If Xvals(iLooper) = NewX(iTest) And Yvals(iLooper) = NewY(iTest) Then
            FoundMatch = True
            Dim iMatch As Long
            iMatch = iTest
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
        If FoundMatch Then
          ' append to matched point's label
          Labels(iMatch) = Labels(iMatch) & ", " & CStr(iLooper)
        Else
          ' add new point
          nPoints = nPoints + 1
          ReDim Preserve NewX(1 To nPoints)
          NewX(nPoints) = Xvals(iLooper)
          ReDim Preserve NewY(1 To nPoints)
          NewY(nPoints) = Yvals(iLooper)
          ReDim Preserve Labels(1 To nPoints)
          Labels(nPoints) = CStr(iLooper)
        End If
      Next

      With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Values = NewY
        .XValues = NewX
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleNone
        Dim iPoint As Long
        For iPoint = 1 To UBound(Labels)
          .Points(iPoint).HasDataLabel = True
          .Points(iPoint).DataLabel.Text = Labels(iPoint)
        Next
      End With
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon! Impressive coding skills!! I have accepted the VBA code as this is what I require, but the one below is also awesome for someone who doesn't use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I did this without VBA, even though I make my living writing VBA.

I've recreated your situation. The XY chart plots Effort and Benefit, and I use column F for the labels (using the value from cells option). Cell F2 has the simple formula `=A2`.

There are two points that overlap, highlighted in light orange, #2 and #6. The labels in the chart overlap.

[image: overlapping labels]

Column E counts the cumulative occurrences of Effort-Benefit pairs using the formula `=COUNTIFS(B$2:B2,B2,C$2:C2,C2)` in cell E2. All values are 1 except for project 6, which is the second of the matched items.

Now I can adjust the label column formula in F2 to

`=REPT("  ",E2-1)&IF(E2>1,REPT(" ",E2-2)&",","")&A2`

which provides a double spaces (E2-1) times, plus (E2-2) extra spaces and a comma if E2>1. This puts blank space and a comma in front af the second label for a point so the first label appears without being blocked. The spacing isn't perfect, but it's better than nothing.

[image: two non-overlapping labels]

And if a third point overlaps (project 8), the formula in column F provides even more blank space so the first two labels aren't blocked by the third.

[image: three non-overlapping labels]